# Rango's Western reference?

Tags: reference, western, rango

The (excellent) *Rango* is filled with references to other movies.

While I found quite a lot of them, I'm stuck on this one.  Which (famous I suppose) western does this scene refer to?

[image]

Comment: I can't connect it to any particular film title, but this is a common trope I think in many westerns. It's often a large flank of Indians or soldiers on top of a steep cliff looking down on the protagonist.

Answer (score 6):

As I've written before, I don't watch westerns, but I just found a clip of Rango that shows the few minutes up to the above screencap. The surrounding area looks like Monument Valley, which is where John Ford is known to make his westerns. Feeling that Rango was looking to employ the well-known, I was concentrating on the John Ford/Monument Valley combination of films in IMDB. I found: [*Stagecoach*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031971/combined), [*My Darling Clementine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038762/combined), *Fort Apache*, *She Wore a Yellow Ribbon*, *Wagon Master*, *Rio Grande*, *The Searchers*, *Sergeant Rutledge* and his last western, *Cheyenne Autumn*. Both *Stagecoach* and *My Darling Clementine* have IMDB images showing similar geography. the *My Darling Clementine* image shows Henry Fonda on a similar overlook. Also, one of many trailers for Rango seemed to concentrate on a shootout; *My Darling Clementine* is described as "A Western retelling the tale of the Shoot-out at the OK Corral". So, that's my new guess.

Comment: Yep - I was looking at Ford films too - +1 for the detective work ;)

Answer (score 6):

For some reason I keep being drawn to The Magnificent Seven - but I have a feeling it's a John Ford film as mentioned elsewhere.

Here's a couple of '7' shots anyway.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've also checked a lot screencaps from this one even if they are not 7 but 11 in Rango. Should perhaps try to check the movie again.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm... Seem like you will have to be cautious as this reminds me of Mos Eisley Spaceport where you won't find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy:

[image]

In case you don't know, this is from Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope.

Comment: This would make sense considering Rango is ILM's first CG feature - but I'm pretty sure the shot is still referencing a different western. I'll post this on FaceBook and see if someone from ILM can answer it. +1 for the logical conclusion though ;)

Comment: @Nobby Yes, I'm almost sure I've seen this scene in a western, but which one? They are quite a lot of them which could match. Thanks for your help.